# Online multiplayer browser-based game server technology?

Tags: ruby, sockets, node.js, socket.io, multiplayer

I would like to build a simple cross-browser multiplayer game (like chess or a card game) which will communicate to a server using sockets.

I have some intermediate knowledge of Ruby language, but I'm not so convinced that it is a good solution for a multi-client server, so a thought that Node.js or Socket.io might be a better one. I know that Java or C++ could be great for the job, but I am not too comfortable with none of them, so that is the reason that I'm levitating towards Server-side JavaScript.

My question is, what do you think is the best solution for a project like this one? What might be the best server-side technology on which I will build an entire game and communication logic? Maybe some combination of them? Any comment regarding speed, server load, hosting solutions and development speed for each of the technologies will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfy with JavaScript, you've got nothing to lose by giving node.js a go: the learning curve will be gentle. It's a pretty cool server tech.

Only disadvantage with node js is of course it won't scale like java. At all. This is often fine for web apps because you can throw a caching layer in front (reverse proxy), which greatly mitigates this. I imagine this won't be reasonable for your application, since the game state will change too frequently.

Node js can "scale" though, by spinning up more instances. If one server can easily accomodate more than one "game world", then this is straightforward. If you need to split a gameworld across multiple servers, then servers must cooperate. Beware this scenario though, it's not as simple as it first may seem: it's called the "multi master" problem and is one of the hungry internet monsters.

Comment: Scalability won't be a problem since this will be a small project, mostly exploratory and to boost my credentials, so I just worry for now not to produce some memory leaks that could clog my server, because I had some memory problems in Java earlier when I was working with threads. Thank you for the answer, I will check Node.js some more and make a decision.

Comment: Sounds like a great match, then! If you want to host a public service, I think Amazon were offering a bottom-level VM free for a year a while back. Maybe that deal is still on.

Comment: Yep, if you're a new customer, you can get a vm on the "Free Tier": http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing

Comment: Oh, one more technology to consider in conjunction with NodeJS: WebSockets, because they offer a low-latency connection to and from the browser. I'd recommend using Google's "Socket.io", which abstracts a handful of different approaches for "realtime" connections (including websockets) to optionally support older browsers. It also provides other important functionality for realtime apps, such as chatrooms, heartbeats, etc.

Comment: Oh, just realised you mentioned socket.io in your question. Yes, you should use it if you use nodejs: it is a nodejs extension.

Comment: If you're looking for a framework, I would strongly recommend http://sailsjs.org, it uses WebSockets and Socket.io and you got some strong architecture with Models, controllers, blueprints and a lot of good stuff.